# Is there a way for my windows service to send an event to my blazor application?

Tags: sql-server, events, windows-services, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm building an application with two parts: a windows service that runs all the time with the ability to email people when a notification arrives for them and a CRUD application built in Blazor in which they can see their notifications.

Right now I have my windows service working with my DB so it knows when something new is added. I was wondering if it would be possible to have my windows service tell my CRUD application when a new entry is added to the DB so I don't need a bunch of DB connections for each user of the CRUD application.

I can just use the one in the windows service and just tell all the CRUD apps to update when a new row appears in the DB using the service. I've been doing some googling but haven't found any great answers yet.

Comment: Is there a way? Yes - sending "messages" between processes is known as [inter-process communication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/interprocess-communications).

Comment: What they said ^ or implement a little signalR hub in the service and connect the blazor app to that.

Comment: More info about Blazor+SignalR here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr-blazor?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio&pivots=webassembly

Comment: And you might need the technique described here, also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubcontext?view=aspnetcore-5.0